# Can JSON be returned "live" using yield return?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

Here's the situation.

What I am working with: 
 - ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API
 - IIS 7.0 to host application
 - C#

I have Web API that gets performance data from remote machines on an intranet and am testing calling the API via URL calls, and this returns JSON. However, it must complete execution first before returning the JSON. So for example, if I return performance monitoring for 10 seconds, I will have to wait 10 seconds before having all the data values displayed.

What I want to do is get it live, so that it will return a value when it reads the performance counter each second and display it in JSON, rather than waiting for everything to be retrieved and then list it all at once. I am attempting to use the YIELD keyword in order to accomplish this, but it still isn't working. The JSON is not displayed in the browser until the method has completely finished.

Here is the code for the repository method and for the coordinating controller action:

From LogDBRepository.cs :

```
public IEnumerable<DataValueInfo> LogTimedPerfDataLive(string macName, string categoryName, string counterName,
                                          string instanceName, string logName, long? seconds)
    {
        iModsDBRepository modsDB = new iModsDBRepository();
        List<MachineInfo> theMac = modsDB.GetMachineByName(macName);

        if (theMac.Count == 0)
            yield break;

        else if (instanceName == null)
        {
            if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName, macName) ||
                !PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(counterName, categoryName, macName))
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
        else if (instanceName != null)
        {
            if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName, macName) ||
                !PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(counterName, categoryName, macName) ||
                !PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists(instanceName, categoryName, macName))
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
        else if (logName == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        // Check if entered log name is a duplicate for the authenticated user
        List<LogInfo> checkDuplicateLog = this.GetSingleLog(logName);
        if (checkDuplicateLog.Count > 0)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory(categoryName, theMac[0].MachineName);
        if (category.CategoryName == null || category.MachineName == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        List<LogInfo> logIt = new List<LogInfo>();
        if (category.CategoryType != PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance)
        {
            List<InstanceInfo> instances = modsDB.GetInstancesFromCatMacName(theMac[0].MachineName, category.CategoryName);

            foreach (InstanceInfo inst in instances)
            {
                if (!category.InstanceExists(inst.InstanceName))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (inst.InstanceName.Equals(instanceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName,
                                                                        inst.InstanceName, theMac[0].MachineName);

                    //CounterSample data = perfCounter.NextSample();
                    //double value = CounterSample.Calculate(data, perfCounter.NextSample());
                    string data = "";
                    List<UserInfo> currUser = this.GetUserByName(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                    string timeStarted = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

                    List<string> dataValues = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
                    {
                        data = "Value " + i + ": " + perfCounter.NextValue().ToString();
                        DataValueInfo datItUp = new DataValueInfo
                        {
                            Value = data
                        };
                        yield return datItUp;
                        dataValues.Add(data);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    string timeFinished = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

                    Log log = new Log
                    {
                        LogName = logName,
                        CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                        InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                        CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                        MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                        TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                        TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                        PerformanceData = string.Join(",", dataValues),
                        UserID = currUser[0].UserID
                    };
                    this.CreateLog(log);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName,
                                                                        "", theMac[0].MachineName);


            string data = "";
            List<UserInfo> currUser = this.GetUserByName(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            string timeStarted = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

            List<string> dataValues = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
            {
                data = "Value " + i + ": " + perfCounter.NextValue().ToString();
                DataValueInfo datItUp = new DataValueInfo
                {
                    Value = data
                };
                yield return datItUp;
                dataValues.Add(data);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            string timeFinished = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

            Log log = new Log
            {
                LogName = logName,
                CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                PerformanceData = string.Join(",", dataValues),
                UserID = currUser[0].UserID
            };
            this.CreateLog(log);
        }

    }
```

From LogController.cs :

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public IEnumerable<DataValueInfo> Log_Perf_Data(string machine_name, string category_name, string counter_name, string instance_name,
                                   string log_name, long? seconds, string live, string enforceQuery)
    {
        LogController.CheckUser();

        // POST api/log/post_data?machine_name=&category_name=&counter_name=&instance_name=&log_name=&seconds=
        if (machine_name != null && category_name != null && counter_name != null && log_name != null && seconds.HasValue && enforceQuery == null)
        {
            List<DataValueInfo> dataVal = logDB.LogTimedPerfDataLive(machine_name, category_name, counter_name, instance_name,
                                   log_name, seconds).ToList();
            logDB.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var val in dataVal)
                yield return val;
        }

        yield break;   
    }
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Iterator functions created with the `yield` keyword are designed to pull the next item on request. They aren't like comet, which pushes data from the server to the client. Perhaps you should do a little research on comet techniques.

Comment: I don't think that the solution is that easy, since the client code will also wait for the full response.
I agree with @KendallFrey, if you want this, you'll have to use comet.

Comment: Thanks. Would I put the comet encoding in the Controller?

Comment: Have you tried streamed output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yield is only creating inmemory object to be returned when response is flushed.

Probably the simplest way to do this is to keep json on the server in a synchronized (static?) variable, when you make request to show performance data you create json, start background worker (google for web backgrounder nuget) which fills data into json object, set running flag and return json object (probably empty on the start).

Then, using setInterval from browser you refresh this data by calling server each second, so every time you get a response with more and more data. When background thread completes, you set running flag to false and in next call you return in your json that information, so you can stop refreshing from client.

This is **NOT** the best way, but probably easiest to implement.